# Different level of aggregation in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How to aggregate at different level on a data.farme.

##### Example:

Data:

```
> dput(sampledata)
structure(list(city = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), workerID = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), salary = c(50000, 1e+05, 60000, 3e+05, 
40000, 80000)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

A solution:

```
left_join(sampledata, 
            sampledata %>%
              group_by(city) %>%
              summarise(city_level_mean = mean(salary)))
```

Output:

```
Joining, by = "city"
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  city  workerID salary city_level_mean
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1 a     1         50000           75000
2 a     2        100000           75000
3 b     3         60000          180000
4 b     4        300000          180000
5 c     5         40000           60000
6 c     6         80000           60000
```

Any other solution?

Comment: `merge(sampledata,aggregate(cbind(city_level_mean=salary)~city,data=sampledata,mean),by="city")`

Comment: @camille I agree with you

Answer (score 3):

A subtlety in Iman's question is whether there is a technique that can be employed that creates the aggregated data column `city_level_mean` without having to re-join the summarized data with the original data frame.

If one uses `dplyr::mutate()` instead of `summarise()` the data can be aggregated without a `left_join`.

```
df <- structure(list(city = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), workerID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), salary = c(50000, 1e+05, 60000, 3e+05, 40000, 80000)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
     group_by(city) %>%
     mutate(city_level_mean = mean(salary))
```

...and the output:

```
> df %>% 
+      group_by(city) %>%
+      mutate(city_level_mean = mean(salary))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   city [3]
  city  workerID salary city_level_mean
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1 a     1         50000           75000
2 a     2        100000           75000
3 b     3         60000          180000
4 b     4        300000          180000
5 c     5         40000           60000
6 c     6         80000           60000
>
```

The same operation using the `data.table` package looks like this. We create a new column, `city_level_mean` as the mean of the `salary` column, using `city` as a by group.

```
# data.table approach
library(data.table)
df_dt <- as.data.table(df)
df_dt[,city_level_mean := mean(salary),city]
df_dt
```

...and the output:

```
> df_dt <- as.data.table(df)
> df_dt[,city_level_mean := mean(salary),city]
> df_dt
   city workerID salary city_level_mean
1:    a        1  5e+04           75000
2:    a        2  1e+05           75000
3:    b        3  6e+04          180000
4:    b        4  3e+05          180000
5:    c        5  4e+04           60000
6:    c        6  8e+04           60000
```